# Integral of $\int x^5 \cdot \sqrt{2 - x^3}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

I have been working on this integral and cannot seem to notice an error I am making. Thanks for any advice in advance!

For the following integral
$$
\int x^5\sqrt{2 - x^3}\,dx 
$$
I considered the $u$-substitution as such
$$
u = x^3, 
\quad 
du = 3x^2\,dx
$$
Then I rewrote the integral as follows:
$$
\frac{1}{3}\int u\sqrt{2 - u}\,du
$$
This I integrated by parts as follows
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{3}\int u\sqrt{2 - u}\, du 
&= \frac{1}{3}\left( 
-\frac{2u\left(2-u\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3} 
+ \frac{2}{3}\int\left(2-u\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\, 
dx \right) \\ 
&= -\frac{2x^3\left( 
2-x^3\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{9} 
- \frac{4\left(2-x^3\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}}{45} + C 
\end{align}
where $C$ is the integrating constant. The issue is that WolframAlpha obtains a different answer as such:
$$
\frac{2}{-9} (2-x^3)^{2/3} \left(x^3+\frac{2}{3}\right) + D
$$
I was expecting it to only differ by the integrating constant but when I graphed them I realised they are not the same. Thanks for any insight into my mistake!

Update: The mistake was found to be in the WolframAlpha interpreter as it was interpreted in the wrong manner, despite the fact that the only different thing I used was a different variable. In conclusion, be sure to put in precise and clear input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to avoid the integration by parts entirely by choosing instead
$$u = 2-x^3, \quad du = -3x^2 \, dx, \quad x^3 = 2-u,$$
hence
$$\begin{align}
\int x^5 \sqrt{2-x^3} \, dx 
&= -\frac{1}{3} \int x^3 \sqrt{2-x^3} (-3x^2) \, dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{3} \int (2-u) \sqrt{u} \, du \\
&= -\frac{1}{3} \int 2 u^{1/2} - u^{3/2} \, du \\
&= -\frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{4}{3} u^{3/2} - \frac{2}{5} u^{5/2} \right) + C \\
&= \frac{2}{15} u^{5/2} - \frac{4}{9} u^{3/2} + C \\
&= \frac{2}{15} (2-x^3)^{5/2} - \frac{4}{9} (2-x^3)^{3/2} + C \\
&= -\frac{2}{45}(4+3x^3)(2-x^3)^{3/2} + C.
\end{align}$$

---

Your antiderivative is equivalent to the above result and therefore is correct:  factorization yields
$$-(2-x^3)^{3/2}\left(\frac{2}{9} x^3 + \frac{4}{45}(2-x^3)\right) = -\frac{2}{45}(2-x^3)^{3/2} (4+3x^3).$$

However, the result that you claim you obtained from Wolfram Alpha is incorrect.  Differentiation of this expression yields
$$\frac{2 x^2 \left(15 x^3-14\right)}{27 \sqrt[3]{2-x^3}}$$
which is not the original integrand.

Comment: I am aware, I wanted to try by parts.

Comment: @TeodorasPaura And you got the right answer and I explained to you that your WA expression is wrong, for reasons that I can't explain because I don't know what you typed into it.  And I showed that by using a different substitution we get the same result as yours, that should convince you that you made no mistake.

Comment: You are very correct, thank you, it was indeed my error with wolfram… I couldn’t figure what was wrong.. Anyway, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned} \int x^5 \sqrt{2-x^3} d x 
= & -\frac{2}{9} \int x^3 d\left(2-x^3\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} \\
= & -\frac{2}{9} x^3\left(2-x^3\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{2}{3} \int x^2\left(2-x^3\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} d x \\
= & -\frac{2}{9} x^3\left(2-x^3\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{4}{45}\left(2-x^3\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}+C \\
= & -\frac{2\left(2-x^3\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{45}\left[5 x^3+2\left(2-x^3\right)\right]+C \\
= & -\frac{2\left(2-x^3\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{45}\left(3 x^3+4\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$